# How to Add Headers to node-http-proxy Response

Tags: node.js, http, https

I need to solve CORS on a third party service, so I want to build a proxy to add the header "Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *".

Why is this code is not adding the header?

```
httpProxy = require('http-proxy');

var URL = 'https://third_party_server...';

httpProxy.createServer({ secure: false, target: URL }, function (req, res, proxy) {

  res.oldWriteHead = res.writeHead;
  res.writeHead = function(statusCode, headers) {
    /* add logic to change headers here */

    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'POST, GET, OPTIONS');

    res.oldWriteHead(statusCode, headers);
  }

  proxy.proxyRequest(req, res, { secure: false, target: URL });

}).listen(8000);
```

Comment: try using the module [cors](https://github.com/expressjs/cors), `npm install cors`

Answer (score 18):

You have the `proxyRes` event available.

So something like that should work:

```
proxy.on('proxyRes', function(proxyRes, req, res) {
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'POST, GET, OPTIONS');
});
```

Full working example (well, when I say full I do not mean this is a secure-failsafe-real proxy, but it does the job for your question):

```
var http = require('http'),
    httpProxy = require('http-proxy');
var proxy = httpProxy.createProxyServer({});
var server = http.createServer(function(req, res) {
    proxy.web(req, res, {
        target: 'https://third_party_server...',
        secure: false,
        ws: false,
        prependPath: false,
        ignorePath: false,
    });
});
console.log("listening on port 8000")
server.listen(8000);

// Listen for the `error` event on `proxy`.
// as we will generate a big bunch of errors
proxy.on('error', function (err, req, res) {
  console.log(err)
  res.writeHead(500, {
    'Content-Type': 'text/plain'
  });
  res.end("Oops");
});

proxy.on('proxyRes', function(proxyRes, req, res) {
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'POST, GET, OPTIONS');
});
```

Comment: So, you've to set the headers in `res` (you can either set in `proxyRes` event or `proxyReq` event). Not in `proxyRes` or `proxyReq` parameters on those events.

Comment: Note that this doesn't seem to work if the target has already set Access-Control-Allow-Origin, since your custom value will be overwritten when the proxy writes to `res`.

Comment: It gives me the error 
"has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status."

Comment: Well, this answer is from 2013, things may have changed a bit. But I think your main problem here is that you do not have a 200 Ok response to your OPTION http query `It does not have HTTP ok status` and that's another problem.

Answer (score 6):

For those coming across this in the future, here's an updated answer. Combining Michael Gummelt's comment and Nicholas Mitrousis' answer, any headers set on `res` will be overridden if the response from upstream in `proxyRes` has the same header set. So to answer the original question:

```
proxy.on('proxyRes', function(proxyRes, req, res) {
 proxyRes.headers["access-control-allow-origin"] = "*";
 proxyRes.headers["Access-Control-Allow-Methods"] = "POST, GET, OPTIONS";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Even though this question is old, it's the first result from Google and the current answer isn't terribly informative.

The first point of note is that `proxyRes` does not have a `setHeader()` method. Additionally, if you try to override a `proxyRes` header with `res.setHeader('Header-to-Override', 'new value')`, it won't work (I assume due to headers being copied from `proxyRes` to `res` after this event is fired.

It appears we're not the only ones with this issue: https://github.com/http-party/node-http-proxy/issues/1401

Here's my solution for adding an additional `cache-control` header in my situation:

```js
proxy.on('proxyRes', function(proxyRes, req, res) {
  if (proxyRes.headers['cache-control']) {
    proxyRes.headers['cache-control'] += ', proxy-revalidate'
  } else {
    proxyRes.headers['cache-control'] = 'proxy-revalidate'
  }
})
```